# Python: Automatic form filling using Selenium gives Error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to acces a website using selenium whenever i try to do the following error appears:

```
ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
```

the code is as follows:

```
from urllib import parse
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class ICAIScraper(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = "https://www.icaionlineregistration.org/Admin_Module/Login.aspx"
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\chromedriver.exe')

    def scrape(self):
        self.driver.get(self.url)
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
        wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id('txt_username').is_displayed() == False)
        print('Yay! on the first page')
        username = self.driver.find_element_by_id('txt_username')
        username.click()
        username.send_keys('username')
        password = self.driver.find_element_by_id('txt_password')
        password.send_keys('password')
        password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   scraper = ICAIScraper()
   scraper.scrape()
```

Comment: can you please add the full error trace. Need to understand which UI element is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

Write a simple function that scrolls to any UI element by id (or you can customize it by using `By` class). Invoking the method by supplying a element's `id` attribute will bring the element to `driver`'s focus.

```
def scroll_to_element_by_id(driver, element_id):
    driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", driver.find_element_by_id(element_id))
```

Sample invocation:

```
scroll_to_element_by_id(self.driver, 'txt_password')
```

Comment: After Invocation I have to do the same thing that i have done in the sample code right?

Comment: Yes, just create a method outside/above your class `ICAIScraper` and invoke it like `scroll_to_element_by_id(self.driver, '<target element id>')`

Comment: feel free to mark as best answer if answered your query.! :)

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all :

```
ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
```

As you have tried to locate the `Username` and `Password` field through the `id` attribute, the fields were not uniquely identified. So we have to adopt a `Locator Strategy` which uniquely identifies the `Username` and `Password` field as follows :

```
# populate the Username field
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td/img[@src='../images/login_userName.png']//following::input[2]").send_keys("username")
# populate the Password field
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td/img[@src='../images/login_password.png']//following::input[2]").send_keys("password")
```

Comment: it gives following error

WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element